# Loping via Bootstrap in Django

Tags: html, django, loops

I want to loop via a `div` with `class="table_cell"`, whenever the loop reaches 3, I will like to have another `div` with `class="table_cell"`, which means, I need new `div` with `class="table_cell"` for every 3 every products in my loop.

```
<div class="table_row">
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
{% for product in featured  %}
    <div class="table_cell">
        <div class="product_item">
            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Thumbmnail - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            <div class="image_wrap">
                <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product actions - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
                <div class="actions_wrap">
                    <div class="centered_buttons">
                        <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="button_dark_grey middle_btn quick_view" data-modal-url="modals/quick_view.html">Details</a>
                        <a href="{{ product.get_add_to_cart_url }}" class="button_blue middle_btn add_to_cart">Add to Cart</a>
                    </div><!--/ .centered_buttons -->
                </div><!--/ .actions_wrap-->
                <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product actions - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
                <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Label - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
                <div class="label_new">featured</div>
                <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End label - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            </div><!--/. image_wrap-->
            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End thumbmnail - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product title & price - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            <div class="description">
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ product.name }}</a>
                <div class="clearfix product_info">
                    <p class="product_price alignleft"><b>{{ product.price|currency }}</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product title & price - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
        </div><!--/ .product_item-->
    </div>
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - End of product - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
{% endfor %}    
</div>
```

Comment: Removed repetitive text and edited code highlighting

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.There is a forloop counter in django, check it out here: [forloop counter docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Using that and a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) this can be achieved:

1. Create a folder called templatetags, inside it create a file `__init__.py`
2. Create a file called `counts.py`

Inside it you can write the following code:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_class(value):
    if value%3 == 0:
        return "table_cell"
    else:
        return ''
```

and in the HTML file:

```
{% load counts %}

<div class="table_row">
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Product - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
{% for product in featured  %}
    <div class="{% get_class forloop.counter %}">
      .......your_other_codes.......
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```